# Coldfusion - using Oauth2.cfc getting "Element STATUS_CODE is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression"

Tags: oauth-2.0, coldfusion

I am new to oauth2 and trying to follow the instructions here: https://github.com/coldfumonkeh/oauth2

I am getting the following error when requesting the access token on my bspace-callback.cfm page:

```
Element STATUS_CODE is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.
 
The error occurred in C:/...oauth2.cfc: line 80

78 :        }
79 :        var result = httpService.send().getPrefix();
80 :        if( '200' == result.ResponseHeader[ 'Status_Code' ] ) {
81 :            stuResponse.success = true;
82 :            stuResponse.content = result.FileContent;
```

Here are my pages:

bspace.cfm

```
<cfset myCfcObject = createObject("component","brightspace")>

<cfset oOauth2 = myCfcObject.init(
    client_id           = 'xxx',
    client_secret       = 'xxx',
    redirect_uri        = 'https://.../bspace-callback.cfm')>
<cfdump var="#myCfcObject#" label="myCfcObject's information."><BR>

<cfset strURL = oOauth2.buildRedirectToAuthURL('enrollment:orgunit:create group:resource:permissions')>
<cfoutput>
    <p>
    <a href="#strURL#">LOGIN!</a>
    </p>
</cfoutput>
```

bspace-callback.cfm

```
<cfsetting requestTimeOut = "9000" />

<cfset myCfcObject = createObject("component","brightspace")>
<cfset oOauth2 = myCfcObject.init(
    client_id           = 'xxx',
    client_secret       = 'xxx',
    redirect_uri        = 'https://.../bspace-callback.cfm')>
<cfdump var="#myCfcObject#" label="myCfcObject's information."><BR>

<cfif isdefined('url.code')>

  <cfset returnData = oOauth2.makeAccessTokenRequest( code = url.code )>

  <cfdump var="#returnData#" label="the access token information">
</cfif>
```

brightspace.cfc (created by me)

```
component extends="oauth2" accessors="true" {

    property name="client_id" type="string";
    property name="client_secret" type="string";
    property name="authEndpoint" type="string";
    property name="accessTokenEndpoint" type="string";
    property name="redirect_uri" type="string";
    
    /**
    * I return an initialized Brightspace object instance.
    * @client_id The client ID for your application.
    * @client_secret The client secret for your application.
    * @authEndpoint The URL endpoint that handles the authorisation.
    * @accessTokenEndpoint The URL endpoint that handles retrieving the access token.
    * @redirect_uri The URL to redirect the user back to following authentication.
    **/
    public brightspace function init(
        required string client_id, 
        required string client_secret, 
        required string authEndpoint = 'https://auth.brightspace.com/oauth2/auth', 
        required string accessTokenEndpoint = 'https://auth.brightspace.com/core/connect/token', 
        required string redirect_uri
    )
    {
        super.init(
            client_id           = arguments.client_id, 
            client_secret       = arguments.client_secret, 
            authEndpoint        = arguments.authEndpoint, 
            accessTokenEndpoint = arguments.accessTokenEndpoint, 
            redirect_uri        = arguments.redirect_uri            
        );
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * I return the URL as a string which we use to redirect the user for authentication.
    **/
    public string function buildRedirectToAuthURL(
    required string scope
    ){
        var sParams = {
            'response_type' = 'code',
            'scope'         = arguments.scope
        };
        return super.buildRedirectToAuthURL( sParams );
    }
    

    /**
    * I make the HTTP request to obtain the access token.
    * @code The code returned from the authentication request.
    **/
    public struct function makeAccessTokenRequest(
        required string code
    ){
        var aFormFields = [
            {
                'name'  = 'grant_type',
                'value' = 'authorization_code'
            }
        ];
        return super.makeAccessTokenRequest(
            code       = arguments.code,
            formfields = aFormFields
        );
    }

}
```

oauth2.cfc (from the github website above)

```
/**
* @displayname oauth2
* @output false
* @hint The oauth2 object.
* @author Matt Gifford
* @website https://www.monkehworks.com
* @purpose A ColdFusion Component to manage authentication using the OAuth2 protocol.
**/
component accessors="true"{

    property name="client_id" type="string";
    property name="client_secret" type="string";
    property name="authEndpoint" type="string";
    property name="accessTokenEndpoint" type="string";
    property name="redirect_uri" type="string";

    /**
    * I return an initialized oauth2 object instance.
    * @client_id The client ID for your application.
    * @client_secret The client secret for your application.
    * @authEndpoint The URL endpoint that handles the authorisation.
    * @accessTokenEndpoint The URL endpoint that handles retrieving the access token.
    * @redirect_uri The URL to redirect the user back to following authentication.
    **/
    public oauth2 function init(
        required string client_id, 
        required string client_secret, 
        required string authEndpoint, 
        required string accessTokenEndpoint, 
        required string redirect_uri
    ){
        setClient_id( arguments.client_id );
        setClient_secret( arguments.client_secret );
        setAuthEndpoint( arguments.authEndpoint );
        setAccessTokenEndpoint( arguments.accessTokenEndpoint );
        setRedirect_uri( arguments.redirect_uri );
        return this;
    }
    
    /**
    * I return the URL as a string which we use to redirect the user for authentication. |
    * The method will handle the client_id and redirect_uri values for you. Anything else you need to send to the provider in the URL can be sent via the parameters argument.
    * @parameters A structure containing key / value pairs of data to be included in the URL string.
    **/
    public string function buildRedirectToAuthURL( struct parameters={} ) {
        return getAuthEndpoint() & '?client_id=' & getClient_id() & '&redirect_uri=' & getRedirect_uri() & buildParamString( argScope = arguments.parameters );
    }
    
    /**
    * I make the HTTP request to obtain the access token.
    * @code The code returned from the authentication request.
    * @formfields An optional array of structs for the provider requirements to add new form fields.
    * @headers An optional array of structs to add custom headers to the request if required.
    **/
    public struct function makeAccessTokenRequest(
        required string code,
        array formfields = [],
        array headers    = []
    ){
        var stuResponse = {};
        var httpService = new http();
        httpService.setMethod( "post" ); 
        httpService.setCharset( "utf-8" );
        httpService.setUrl( getAccessTokenEndpoint() );
        if( arrayLen( arguments.headers ) ){
            for( var item in arguments.headers ){
                httpService.addParam( type="header", name=item[ 'name' ],  value=item[ 'value' ] );
            }
        }
        httpService.addParam( type="formfield", name="client_id",    value=getClient_id() );
        httpService.addParam( type="formfield", name="client_secret", value=getClient_secret() );
        httpService.addParam( type="formfield", name="code",         value=arguments.code );
        httpService.addParam( type="formfield", name="redirect_uri",  value=getRedirect_uri() );
        if( arrayLen( arguments.formfields ) ){
            for( var item in arguments.formfields ){
                httpService.addParam( type="formfield", name=item[ 'name' ],  value=item[ 'value' ] );
            }
        }
        var result = httpService.send().getPrefix();
        if( '200' == result.ResponseHeader[ 'Status_Code' ] ) {
            stuResponse.success = true;
            stuResponse.content = result.FileContent;
        } else {
            stuResponse.success = false;
            stuResponse.content = result.Statuscode;
        }
        return stuResponse;
    }

    /**
    * I make the HTTP request to refresh the access token.
    * @refresh_token The refresh_token returned from the accessTokenRequest request.
    **/
    public struct function refreshAccessTokenRequest(
        required string refresh_token,
        array formfields = [],
        array headers    = []
    ){
        var stuResponse = {};
        var httpService = new http();
        httpService.setMethod( "post" ); 
        httpService.setCharset( "utf-8" );
        httpService.setUrl( getAccessTokenEndpoint() );
        httpService.addParam( type="header", name="Content-Type", value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
        if( arrayLen( arguments.headers ) ){
            for( var item in arguments.headers ){
                httpService.addParam( type="header", name=item[ 'name' ],  value=item[ 'value' ] );
            }
        }
        httpService.addParam( type="formfield", name="client_id",    value=getClient_id() );
        httpService.addParam( type="formfield", name="client_secret", value=getClient_secret() );
        httpService.addParam( type="formfield", name="refresh_token", value=arguments.refresh_token );
        httpService.addParam( type="formfield", name="grant_type",  value="refresh_token" );
        if( arrayLen( arguments.formfields ) ){
            for( var item in arguments.formfields ){
                httpService.addParam( type="formfield", name=item[ 'name' ],  value=item[ 'value' ] );
            }
        }
        var result = httpService.send().getPrefix();
        if( '200' == result.ResponseHeader[ 'Status_Code' ] ) {
            stuResponse.success = true;
            stuResponse.content = result.FileContent;
        } else {
            stuResponse.success = false;
            stuResponse.content = result.Statuscode;
        }
        return stuResponse;
    }
    
    /**
    * I return a string containing any extra URL parameters to concatenate and pass through when authenticating.
    * @argScope A structure containing key / value pairs of data to be included in the URL string.
    **/
    public string function buildParamString( struct argScope={} ) {
        var strURLParam = '';
        if( structCount( arguments.argScope ) ) {
            for( var key in arguments.argScope ) {
                if( listLen( strURLParam ) ) {
                    strURLParam = strURLParam & '&';
                }
                strURLParam = strURLParam & lcase( key ) & '=' & trim( arguments.argScope[ key ] );
            }
            strURLParam = '&' & strURLParam;
        }
        return strURLParam;
    }

    /**
    * Returns the properties as a struct
    */
    public struct function getMemento(){
        var result = {};
        for( var thisProp in getMetaData( this ).properties ){
            if( structKeyExists( variables, thisProp[ 'name' ] ) ){
                result[ thisProp[ 'name' ] ] = variables[ thisProp[ 'name' ] ];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

I am unsure how to fix since it seems no one else is having this problem when I googled for it, so I know I must be doing something really wrong.

Your help is greatly appreciated and thank you.

Comment: Have you dumped `result` to see if the key `status_code` exists where you're requesting it? Does `result.ResponseHeader` exist? If so, then does `result.ResponseHeader.status_code` exist? The error assumes it doesn't. 

Also, why are you using a CFC wrapper that is over three years old? Have you tried accessing their Oauth2 endpoint without the wrapper? You shouldn't need it.

Comment: If `status_code` doesn't exist in a CFHTTP result, it usually means that the HTTP connection could not be established (either the host is unreachable or there's a handshake/certificate issue). The code doesn't check this at all.

Comment: ColdFusion and Lucee have slightly different behaviors in their cfhttp result.  I assume this code was written for Lucee and you're using it on ColdFusion.